# gnome-tweaks on ubuntu with i3wm throws freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gnome, i3

I'm running Linux Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS along with i3wm.

I'm trying to run gnome-tweaks to adjust the theme, but get following error:

```
gnome-tweaks
WARNING : Error getting shell mode
CRITICAL: Error getting shell version
WARNING : Could not list shell extensions
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gtweak/tweaks/tweak_group_appearance.py", line 144, in __init__
    extensions = self._shell.list_extensions()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gtweak/gshellwrapper.py", line 76, in list_extensions
    return self._proxy.proxy_extensions.ListExtensions()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gi/overrides/Gio.py", line 349, in __call__
    result = self.dbus_proxy.call_sync(self.method_name, arg_variant,
gi.repository.GLib.GError: g-dbus-error-quark: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.gnome.Shell was not provided by any .service files (2)
```

The app is opening, but no changes take any effect.

I tried uninstalling/resinstalling gnome-shell, gnome-tweaks, installing i3-gnome, restarting gnome-shell.

When trying to restart gnome-shell I get this:

```
libmutter-Message: 19:02:41.693: Running GNOME Shell (using mutter 42.5) as a X11 window and compositing manager

** (gnome-shell:248303): WARNING **: 19:02:42.136: ATK Bridge is disabled but a11y has already been enabled.
Window manager warning: Display “:0” already has a window manager; try using the --replace option to replace the current window manager.
GNOME Shell failed to start: Failed to acquire window manager ownership%
```

That makes sense because I'm running i3wm.

I was able to successfully run the same configuration on another version of Ubuntu.

Is there a known solution to fix this issue?